# Composition of Reflection Is a Rotation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if $T_{1},T_{2}$ are reflections in lines through O then $T_{1}\circ T_{2}$ is a rotation about O.

Once again, a hint would be preferable to an answer. I'm not familiar with these types of linear transformations, as I am not accustomed to thinking of them as functions. Thanks in advance for everyone who answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you requested a hint, go ahead and think of the transformations as matrices, and treat composition as multiplication. Otherwise, think about how reflection changes chirality, but two reflections would leave chirality unchanged.

Comment: Sorry, I'm somewhat new to the subject; what is chirality?

Comment: It's also called handedness. A right hand in a mirror looks like a left hand, and so we say the reflection changes handedness. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality

Comment: Or orientation.